# Mongoose query based on foreign key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Leave Schema**

```
mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String
});
```

**Status Schema**

```
mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    LeaveId:  String,
    Time: Date
});
```

Here **LeaveId** in **Status** schema is the reference of **_id** for **Leave** Schema. You might have guessed **Leave** and **Status** have one to many relationship.

Now I want to find the list of **status** which contains only the **latest status** for each **leave**.

**Example**
Leave Collection

```
[
    {
        _id: '<id-1>'
    },
    {
        _id: '<id-2>'
    }
]
```

Status Collection

```
[
    {
        _id: '<id-3>',
        LeaveId: '<id-1>',
        Time: 2013-0-0
    },
    {
        _id: '<id-4>',
        LeaveId: '<id-1>',
        Time: 2014-0-0
    },
    {
        _id: '<id-5>',
        LeaveId: '<id-2>',
        Time: 2016-0-0
    },
    {
        _id: '<id-6>',
        LeaveId: '<id-2>',
        Time: 2015-0-0
    }
]
```

Expected Output

```
[
    {
        _id: '<id-4>',
        LeaveId: '<id-1>',
        Time: 2014-0-0
    },
    {
        _id: '<id-5>',
        LeaveId: '<id-2>',
        Time: 2016-0-0
    }
]
```

Comment: Also `LeaveId:  String` is just dead wrong. This relates to the `_id` in the `Leave` collection, and that property is an `ObjectId`. Both need to be the same type for any kind of referenced "join".

Comment: @NeilLunn, Both are of string type

Comment: @NeilLunn, the question you referred just solves this problem partially. Could you have another look?

Comment: It solves it completely. Do you think you could be quiet and actually spend more than 5 minutes understanding it? From my perspective, if you had to ask the question at all then you have not understood the answers given already in such a short space of time.